# Strange Xcode linker warning building Poco C++ app

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, poco-libraries

Has anyone else seen these linker warnings when building a Poco C++ app for iOS with Xcode 6?

```
ld: warning: direct access in std::__1::vector<Poco::Dynamic::Var, std::__1::allocator<Poco::Dynamic::Var> > const& Poco::Dynamic::Var::extract<std::__1::vector<Poco::Dynamic::Var, std::__1::allocator<Poco::Dynamic::Var> > >() const to global weak symbol typeinfo for std::__1::vector<Poco::Dynamic::Var, std::__1::allocator<Poco::Dynamic::Var> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in std::__1::vector<Poco::Dynamic::Var, std::__1::allocator<Poco::Dynamic::Var> > const& Poco::Dynamic::Var::extract<std::__1::vector<Poco::Dynamic::Var, std::__1::allocator<Poco::Dynamic::Var> > >() const to global weak symbol typeinfo for std::__1::vector<Poco::Dynamic::Var, std::__1::allocator<Poco::Dynamic::Var> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in std::__1::vector<Poco::Dynamic::Var, std::__1::allocator<Poco::Dynamic::Var> > const& Poco::Dynamic::Var::extract<std::__1::vector<Poco::Dynamic::Var, std::__1::allocator<Poco::Dynamic::Var> > >() const to global weak symbol typeinfo for std::__1::vector<Poco::Dynamic::Var, std::__1::allocator<Poco::Dynamic::Var> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in std::__1::vector<Poco::Dynamic::Var, std::__1::allocator<Poco::Dynamic::Var> > const& Poco::Dynamic::Var::extract<std::__1::vector<Poco::Dynamic::Var, std::__1::allocator<Poco::Dynamic::Var> > >() const to global weak symbol typeinfo for std::__1::vector<Poco::Dynamic::Var, std::__1::allocator<Poco::Dynamic::Var> > means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
```

And if so, did you determine what causes them and how to resolve them?

Edit: Based on other threads on this topic, I've verified "Symbols hidden by default" is set to YES on all projects, including Poco.

Thanks.

Comment: is this error or warning?

Answer (score 1):

Had tons of these warnings - all about references to global weak symbol typeinfo - in my iOS project with multiple static libraries.

Finally found a solution:

Don't set "Symbols hidden by default" to YES. Set it to its default value - select relevant line in "Build settings", hit delete. Here it seems to resolve to 'yes' for my main iOS executable and 'no' for the static libraries.

After doing so, all warnings about direct access to global weak symbols are gone and my whole project appears to work correctly.

I hope this is helpful.